# How to get vectorlayer from json openlayer 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, openlayers-3

In below script I have added vector layer vectorLayer,vectorLayer5,vectorLayer1

How can I get that layer from json.. want to add multiple layers from external json file with that icon png image

```js
// we change this on input change
var radius = 10;
  longitude = 400000;
  latitude = 300000;


var styleFunction = function() {
  return new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: radius,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: [51, 51, 51],
        width: 2
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [51, 51, 51, .3]
      })
    })
  });
};

var update = function(value) {
var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
  radius = value;
  vectorLayer.setStyle(styleFunction);
 if(wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(),iconFeature5.getGeometry().getCoordinates())<=radius){
      vectorLayer5.setVisible(true);
      console.log('a');
  }
  else{
      vectorLayer5.setVisible(false);
      console.log('b');
  }
}

var feature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([longitude, latitude]));
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [feature]
  }),
  style: styleFunction
});
 var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
   source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
     url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.json',
     crossOrigin: ''
   })
 });

// icon marker start here

var iconFeature5 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([longitude, latitude]),
  name: 'Missing Person',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500
});

var vectorSource5 = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature5]
});

var vectorLayer5 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource5
});

var iconStyle5 = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    
    src: 'https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/41094/2833021/7279fac0-cfcb-11e3-9789-24436486a8b1.png'
  }))
});
iconFeature5.setStyle(iconStyle5);

// 2nd marker

  longitude1 = 100000;
  latitude1 = 100000;
var iconFeature1 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([longitude1, latitude1]),
  name: 'Missing Person',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500
});

var vectorSource1 = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature1]
});

var vectorLayer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource1
});

iconFeature1.setStyle(iconStyle5);



var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer,vectorLayer,vectorLayer5,vectorLayer1],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [400000, 400000],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.input {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/build/ol.js"></script>

<div class="input">
  <input type="range" id="range" min="10" max="50" onchange="update(this.value)">
  <input type="text" id="range" value="10">
</div>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web mapping we call json data with geometries as geojson and it has its own extension in text files. In order to call a geojson file to OL3 you'll have to load it to the vector source of the layer, Here is a part of a code to load external geojson file to an OL3 map:

```
var vectorSource=new ol.source.Vector({
      projection : 'EPSG:4326', // or 'EPSG:8357'
      url: 'yourExternalFile.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
var vectorLayer=new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'geojson layer',
    source: vectorSource,
    style:new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
            anchor: [0.5, 0],
            anchorOrigin: 'bottom-left',
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            src: 'yourImage.png'
        }))
    })
});
```

PS: the examples on Openlayers 3 website are very useful when you combine them

Comment: In url if give pass local path (url: 'multipoint.geojson') its give error 404 (Not Found) add if i give add url:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapbox/cover-bench/89a8da794ef8c9434b8745d306f1a1b590bba97a/fixtures/'

Comment: you should check the path of your geojson file from the HTML file

Comment: Image and multipoint.geojson location is same if I added url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapbox/cover-bench/89a8da794ef8c9434b8745d306f1a1b590bba97a/fixtures/multipoint.geojson' local images are coming nut when add local path its not work

Comment: // vector layer
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
         projection : 'EPSG:4326',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: 'multipoint.geojson'
    }),
    style: [
    new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            src: 'resources/icon.png',
            anchor: [0.5, 1]
        })
    })]
});

Comment: Hey its My bad I save that from noteapad so its save like multipoint.geojson.txt. Now I modified the extension and its working. Thanks Hicham Zouarhi